# What PDE and initial conditions does $v(x,t)$ satisfy?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

If I have:
$u_t=ku_{xx}$ for $0<x<\infty$ and $0<t<\infty$

$u(x,0)=x$, for $t=0$ and $0<x<\infty$

$u_x(0,t)-2u(0,t)=0$, for $x=0$

Then I let $f(x)=x$ for $x>0$ and $f(x)=x+1-e^{2x}$ for $x<0$

I also have that $v(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt(4 \pi kt)}$ $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(x-y)^2/4kt} f(y)dy$

I'm trying to figure out what PDE and initial condition does $v(x,t)$ satisfy for $-\infty<x<\infty$ but can't seem to figure it out? Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: I'd suggest you look at this page where you can find the Green function for the heat equation with Robin b.c.http://greensfunction.unl.edu/home/index.html

Comment: @user179523: Should $e^{-(x-y)/4kt}$ instead be $e^{-(x-y)^{2}/4kt}$? Otherwise, the integrand is not integrable on the nonnegative real axis.

Comment: yes, sorry about that I just edited it so it should be correct now

Comment: @user179523: It's not clear to me how the Initial/Boundary Value Problem (IBVP) you describe at the beginning of your question relates to what you are ultimately asking. Also, why are you asking what IBVP $v$ solves, rather than formulating the IBVP and then solving it?

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider the following more general initial/boundary value problem (IBVP):

$$\begin{cases} u_{t}(x,t)-ku_{xx}(x,t)=0 & {\mathbb{R}_{+}\times\mathbb{R}_{+}}\\ u(x,t)=\varphi(x) & {\mathbb{R}_{+}\times\left\{t=0\right\}}\\ u_{x}(x,t)-hu(x,t)=0 & {\left\{x=0\right\}\times\mathbb{R}_{+}}\end{cases}$$

where $\varphi$ is continuous and doesn't grow too fast, say polynomial growth, and $h,k$ are positive constants. Replacing $u$ by $w(x,k^{-1}t)$, we may assume that $k=1$.

We want to extend the initial data $\varphi$ to the entire real line in order to obtain an initial value problem. We seek an extension $\tilde{\varphi}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ satisfying such that $\tilde{\varphi}|_{\mathbb{R}_{+}}=\varphi$ and

$$\tilde{\varphi}'(x)-h\tilde{\varphi}(x)=-\varphi'(-x)+h\varphi(-x), \ \text{ $(x<0)$}$$

and $\tilde{\varphi}(0)=\varphi(0)$. The reason for this second condition is that the function solution $v$ to the initial value problem

$$\begin{cases} v_{t}(x,t)-v_{xx}(x,t) & {\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}_{+}}\\ v(x,t)=\tilde{\varphi}(x) & {\mathbb{R}\times\left\{t=0\right\}}\end{cases}$$

will satisfy the boundary condition $v_{x}(x,t)-hv(x,t)=0$ on $\left\{x=0\right\}\times\mathbb{R}_{+}$. This follows from using the fundamental solution of the heat operator, differentiating inside the integral, and the uniqueness result for the Cauchy problem on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ (remember $\varphi$ satisfies the growth condition).

You can solve the ODE for $\tilde{\varphi}$ to find that

$$\displaystyle\tilde{\varphi}(x)=\begin{cases} \varphi(x) & {x\geq 0}\\ \varphi(-x)+2h\int_{0}^{x}e^{h(x-y)}\varphi(-y)dy & {x<0} \end{cases}$$

In the case $\varphi(x)=x$, $\tilde{\varphi}$ is precisely the function $f$ defined in your question. Using the fundamental solution of the heat operator, we see that

$$v(x,t)=(4\pi t)^{-1/2}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-\frac{\left|x-y\right|^{2}}{4t}}\tilde{\varphi}(y)dy$$

Setting $u(x,t):=v(x,t)$ for $x\geq 0$ gives a solution to the original IBVP.